# Browser devtools: How to figure out the element's event context

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-devtools, firefox-developer-tools, firefox-developer-edition

I'm figuring out how React Documentation page's search feature works: https://reactjs.org/ .

I know they use [DocSearch](https://github.com/algolia/docsearch) but I would like to know what happens behind the scene.

Currently I'm trying to know what happens when I type anything in the search bar. Here is what I got in the Chrome dev tools:

Flame graph:
[image]

Source window (to see the Call Stack)
[image]

Using the Flame Graph and the Call Stack show what functions are called during the event, as well as what event are being triggered (in this example, `Event:keypress` -> `Event:textinput` -> `Event:input` -> `function call`)

The problem is, how do I know in which element of DOM triggered the event using devtools? I know it was `#algolia-doc-search` triggered `input` event by looking at the source code, but I would like to know a more convenient way to track DOM events.

Thanks!

Just in case, Firefox Dev Edition doesn't help much neither.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the Chrome and Firefox DevTools provide an easy way to stop the script execution on DOM events. They call this feature "Event Listener Breakpoints".

In the Chrome DevTools this [can be found in the *Sources* panel](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints#event-listeners):

[image: Event Listener Breakpoints in Chrome DevTools]

In the Firefox DevTools the feature is [located in the *Debugger* panel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/Set_event_listener_breakpoints):

[image: Event Listener Breakpoints in Firefox DevTools]

Once you have check the events you want to listen for, triggering them will halt the script execution and jump directly to the line where the event occurred. They also provide a hint at their right side panels what event occurred.

In Chrome that looks like this:

[image: Chrome DevTools stopped at event]

In Firefox it's very similar:

[image: Firefox DevTools stopped at event]

To get the element that triggered the event, check the *Scope* panel. In there you see all variables available in the current execution context. The `this` scope in there refers to the target element. Alternatively, you can expand the event variable (in the example that's `e`) and search for the `target` attribute.

Here's how it looks like in Chrome:

[image: Event target in Chrome DevTools]

And again, in Firefox very similar:

[image: Event target in Firefox DevTools]

Pro tip: Hovering the element will highlight it in the page. And you can also select it in the *Elements*/*Inspector* panel by right-clicking the element and selecting *Reveal in Elements panel* (Chrome) or clicking the target icon next to it (Firefox).

Comment: Thank you for the cool trick, but I would like to know which DOM element (Like button, input, form, etc.) triggers the event using the dev tool, not just breaking at the event.

Comment: Right. You can easily get to the event target through the *Scopes* panel. I've adjusted my answer to explain how that works.